# RS-25 Component weight

Tags: space-shuttle, propulsion, engine-design, nozzle, combustion-chamber

I need to determine the weight for specific components of the RS-25 Rocket engine. Namely the combustion chamber and nozzle separate from all other engine components?

I must have found hundreds of pages containing fun facts about the shuttle rocket engine. But nothing that will tell me the weight of the combustion chamber and nozzle in isolation.

Comment: @TheRocketfan That doesn't make sense; 1) that question is about the mass flow rate of propellants, and 2) it already has an answer about mass flow rate of propellants.

Comment: Hi @Slartibartfast, it would be better if you described what you've tried so far. Have you searched for documents about this? Have you found anything = perhaps a breakdown by mass but without enough granularity? You're really asking "What is the mass of the RS-25 combustion chamber, and of the nozzle?" right? Have you read some articles or blog posts or watched some videos or found some online books and they don't have what you need?

Comment: Simple "please look this up for me" questions usually don't do well in most Stack Exchange sites, and the tooltip guidelines for downvoting begins "[This question does not show any research effort...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02cVC.png)" I didn't downvote, but probably other folks will if you don't address this. *Thanks, and Welcome to Space SE!*

Comment: @The Rocket Fan That's a completely different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is old information from the old (pre-flight) Rockwell document [*Space Shuttle Main Engine Design Features* (BC73-110)](https://archive.org/download/ssme-design-features-1973_202401/SSME_Design_Features_1973.pdf).

However, it is the only document I know of that gives component weights for the SSME. So treat them as ballpark figures.

From that document (pages 304-115T and 304-116T), the MCC weighed 440 pounds (~200 kg) and the nozzle weighed 946 pounds (~430 kg).